# Plotting partial sum with complex number

Tags: plotting, complex, summation, list-manipulation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{2\pi in\sqrt2}$$

We have to use `Accumulate` and `ListLinePlot`, and my implementation so far with upper bound 50 (any upper bound is fine) is having trouble with the complex number. I tried to use `Relm`, but same thing happens.

```
Sums= Accumulate[e^(2*pi*I*#*sqrt[2]) & /@ Range[50]];
ListLinePlot[Sums, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has many syntax errors, read the manual.
And a hint, do not use names that start with a capital letter. Keywords in MMA start like this.

Here is the changed code:

```
sums = Accumulate[E^(2*Pi*I*#*Sqrt[2]) & /@ Range[50]] // N;
sums = ReIm /@ sums;
sums = ListLinePlot[sums, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Tyvm. This is much clearer and helped ne understand.

Comment: Here is another hint for free: Multiplication by Exp[ I phi] is a rotation in the complex plane by the angle phi (in radians).

Answer (score 1):

Since V12, there is `ComplexListPlot`:

```
ComplexListPlot[
 Accumulate[E^(2*Pi*I*Range[50]*Sqrt[2])],
 Joined -> True
 ]
```

[image]